# Angular 2 set local storage item as int?

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have the following code:

```
if (this.num)
                localStorage.setItem('num', this.num++);
            else
                localStorage.setItem('num_', 1);
```

to save a count of users in my website, but when I run my app I get `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` error.
Why I can't use number type in my local storage?

Comment: It should be string `'' + this.num++` and `'1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var number = 1;
localStorage.setItem('item', number.toString());
```

And when you retreive the number as a string from localStorage, convert it to a number again.